# How can I specify that (at least) one of two packages needs to be installed?

Tags: python, dependency-management, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I'm the maintainer of `pypdf` and we support two cryptography packages:

- cryptography
- pycryptodome

To get the full functionality, the user needs to have one of them installed. It doesn't matter which one.

How do I specify this in the `pyproject.toml`?

I currently have:

```
[project.optional-dependencies]
crypto = [
    "cryptography; python_version >= '3.7'",
    "PyCryptodome; python_version == '3.6'",
]
```

But when the user has Python >= 3.7 and PyCryptodome, it would be fine as well.

Comment: Side question: wouldn't it be better to just use one instead of giving a choice that does not change anything ?

Comment: Good question (+1). I'm uncertain (1) Users seem to have issues with installing cryptography packages. Maybe one works and the other doesn't (2) They are also rather big. In general, I think `cryptography` is preferable. But if you are working with Ethereum (web3), you already have `PyCryptodome`. Then you wouldn't need to install anything else.

Comment: pyproject.toml can't specify this directly, but here's what I would suggest: make three sets of options. `crytpo` where you just pick one, `crypto_cryptography` where you specify `cryptography`, and `crypto_pycryptodome` where you specify `PyCryptodome`. Now users who don't care which one will get your choice, and users who already bundle one or the other can match.